# How does AngularJS compile directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a better understanding how AngularJS compiles directives and updates the view.

Here's my specific problem. I have a directive like so:

```
angular.module('directives', [])

.directive('test', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope : { foo : '=' }, 
      template: '<div id={{foo.id}}>{{foo.data}}</div>'
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          document.getElementById(scope.foo.id); /*1*/
      }
    }
 });
```

At point 1 `scope.foo.id` *is* `defined`. However, the template for the directive has not been compiled yet, so the div id is not set, and `getElementById` returns `null`. Once the page is completely rendered, and I look at the compiled template, all of the template id's have been successfully set to foo.id

What am I missing here?

It's also important to note that for my particular case I need to explicitly interact with the template `div` by it's id.

EDIT: added a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6c4nb/8/

Comment: Question, it says you need to interact with the template, any details on what you want to do with that template?

Comment: I'm trying to initialize a plugin on the element that explicitly needs  the element id to be passed into it.

Comment: Can you throw this into a fiddle? It is hard to understand exactly what you are doing without the html and full js.

Comment: Can you provide me with the HTML for your plugin? Essentially, what you do is use element.html( {{ your plugin goes here }} ); then execute a $compile(element.contents())(scope);

Comment: I'm working on a fiddle now.

Comment: @mister_rampage the plugin is jwplayer, basically its going to take whatever element i specify and turn it into a player

Comment: @ZackArgyle I created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/6c4nb/2/

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now.. @Dan what you're looking for is the scope variable. Here's the question, did you want to manipulate foo or is it readonly?

Comment: @mister_rampage It's read only.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you, sorry, I don't think I can answer this for you. I suspect it has something to do with your template as you need to set foo="foo" somewhere in order to have a bi-directional scope, but your fiddle doesn't have the scope variable set in the directive.

Comment: @mister_rampage I apologize. I just missed it on the fiddle. I updated it so it's correct.

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6c4nb/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, given the limited information, I was able to get the element working for you. I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but you need to set the id of the element within the directive.

If someone with better understanding can explain, I'd like to know why the id doesn't get bound within the template. It appears that if you set the id from the directive, it works fine. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6c4nb/11/))

@Dan I also had to change your ID to use the word `test-` in front of it because the HTML spec does not allow id's to start with numerical values. According to the spec:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);

testApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = [
        { id: 1, msg: 'this is a nice message'}, 
        { id: 2, msg: 'this message is also nice'}, 
        { id: 3, msg: 'yet another message'}
    ];
}]); 

testApp.directive('plugin', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'EA', 
        template: '<div>{{foo.msg}}</div>',
        scope: {'foo': '='},
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {
                    element.attr('id', 'test-' + scope.foo.id);
                    console.log(document.getElementById('test-' + scope.foo.id));
                    /* This does not provide a null value */
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Foo is defined on a controller, and I'm defining it on the scope of the directive with `scope: {foo = '='}`. I'm just trying to access it so I can do some DOM manipulation on the element.

Comment: Couldn't you just modify the DOM using the element variable? Any chance you could get a jsfiddle illustrating what you want?

Comment: Refer to the comment I made above. I need the id string, and the element needs to be compiled at that time.

Comment: Make sure you understand the scope setting for directives. You'll need the understand when to set scope to false/true/or {}. See the link in the answer.

Comment: I'm explicitly trying to isolate the scope... I don't want `scope: false`

Comment: Please provide feedback on the downvote as well. Thanks.